# Flutter Moor package import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-moor

I am working on a Flutter app and trying to use [Moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor) package for DB. I have included all dependencies in the `pubspec.yaml` file, created my table entity and also the database.

Every time I run the app, I get this error:

```
Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime
```

Here is the `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.2
  moor: ^3.3.1
  sqlite3_flutter_libs: ^0.2.0
  path_provider: ^1.6.14
  path: ^1.7.0

dev_dependencies:
  moor_generator: ^3.3.1
  build_runner: ^1.7.3
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Here is also my table entity:

```
class DBEntrie extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer()();
  TextColumn get uuid => text()();
  TextColumn get name => text()();
  TextColumn get title => text()();

  @override
  Set<Column> get primaryKey => {id};
}
```

and the DB class:

```
LazyDatabase _openConnection() {
  return LazyDatabase(() async {
    final dbFolder = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File(p.join(dbFolder.path, 'entriesdb.sqlite'));
    return VmDatabase(file, logStatements: true);
  });
}

@UseMoor(tables: [DBEntries])
class MyDatabase extends _$MyDatabase {
  MyDatabase() : super(_openConnection());
  @override
  int get schemaVersion => 1;

  Future<List<DBEntrie>> getAllDBEntries() => select(_dBEntries).get();
}
```

It generated the table and the database file correctly. But at run it gives this error. How can I fix it? Is there any missing dependency? Should I change the Dart version I am using for the app?

Comment: Hey there, could you post you `flutter doctor`

Comment: @ByteMe This is the version when flutter doctor: Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, ... )

Comment: I also need to see the dart version from the `flutter doctor`

Comment: @ByteMe Dart version 2.9.1

Answer (score 0):

The [moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor) package that was previously published in pub.dev was discontinued and replaced by the new package [drift](https://pub.dev/packages/drift). I suggest to use the latest plugin as this is being supported than the latter.